# Price Alert software

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a software that I can use for the following:

I have competitors prices in a csv (automatic updated csv), and I'm looking for a software that can process this csv file each hour, and alerts me when any price drops below of mine from the competitors.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Well, idea #1: proof-read after copy-pasting – or you invite down-votes (your post here started with "-4 down vote favorite" before Pierre fixed that up ;)

Comment: Free or paid software?

Comment: It seems unlikely that there is anything quite like this.  However, since you are using csv, you should be able to create a solution using nothing more than MS Excel and the Windows Task Scheduler.

You'll need to create a VBA macro in your own Excel price sheet that uses lookups to compare against the competitor prices, and creates an alert if there is a problem.  If no problem, it closes the spreadsheet.

You can automate this with the Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking on something like this, but... If there was a software in which I could map the fields, that would be better.